# How can I additionally zip list into already zipped list?

Tags: python, list, python-itertools, iterable-unpacking

Assume I have a list of two-element tuples and a list of (not tuple) literals e.g. integer:

```
a = [('x', 'a'), ('y', 'b'), ('z', 'c')]
b = [1, 2 ,3]
```

And I want to make a list of three-element tuples so I coded like below:

```
zipped = zip((t[0] for t in a), (t[1] for t in a), b)
assert zipped == [('x', 'a', 1), ('y', 'b', 2), ('z', 'c', 3)]
```

My current code works pretty well but I want to know that is there any more efficient and elegant recipe however my code have to iterate and unpack every tuples twice.
Can anyone please advise?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using list comprehension, tuple unpacking:

```
>>> a = [('x', 'a'), ('y', 'b'), ('z', 'c')]
>>> b = [1, 2 ,3]
>>> [(x,y,z) for (x,y), z in zip(a, b)]
[('x', 'a', 1), ('y', 'b', 2), ('z', 'c', 3)]
```

---

```
>>> a = [('x', 'a'), ('y', 'b'), ('z', 'c')]
>>> b = [1, 2 ,3]
>>> [x + (y,) for x, y in zip(a, b)]
[('x', 'a', 1), ('y', 'b', 2), ('z', 'c', 3)]
```

Answer (score 3):

one without using for loop,

```
zip(*(zip(*a)+ [b]))
```

Comment: No need to call `tuple`: `zip(*(zip(*a) + [b]))` also work. BTW, this will not work in Python 3.x becaue [`zip` in Python 3.x](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) returns an iterator instead of list.

Comment: Not using 3.x but I suppose you can convert iterator to list using list(). Probably zip(*(list(zip(*a))+ [b])) should work there.